# Python json get specific story and image

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very new to Python and I have a json news feed that I need to get a selected 'title' and image 'src'.

I have managed to get to print all the 'title' and just the image 'src' that says "1024 landscape".
How can I print, for example, just the second title? How do I address that particular one?
The feed is : http://www.stuff.co.nz/_json/ipad-big-picture

```
for story in data.get('stories', []):

    print 'Title:', story['title']

    for img in story.get('images', []):

        for var in img.get('variants', []):
            if var.get('layout') == "1024 Landscape":
                print '    img:', (var.get('src')).split('/')[-1], ' layout:', var.get('layout')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First just get your stories object (list of dicts):

```
stories = data.get('stories', [])
```

Once you have this list you can just access by index:

```
if len(stories) >= 2:
    print stories[1]['title']
```

Or try first and catch the exception:

```
i = 1
try:
    print stories[i]['title']
except IndexError:
    print "Story does not exist at index %d" % i
```

So, when trying to get all 1024 Landscape images for a specific story, it might look like this:

```
imgs = set()
for img in stories[1].get('images', []):
    for variant in img.get('variants', []):
        if variant.get('layout') == '1024 Landscape':
            imgs.add(variant['src'])
print imgs
set([u'http://static.stuff.co.nz/1341147692/827/7202827.jpg'])
```

Comment: Thanks jdi. This does display the selected story. How would I display the image from that story that has the the layout '1024 landscape'? Under images there are multiple images.

Comment: You would have to do exactly what your example does, looping down over the images and variants and returning the `src` with the matching `layout` value. The only difference now is that you aren't looping over every story, but rather a specific index.